# If $m(A)+m(B)>1$, then $A\cap B\neq \varnothing$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

A question from a test in the theory of measure from last year that I do not find a solution to:

Let $A,B\subset [0,1]$ be lebesgue measurable sets.

A. If $m(A)+m(B)>1$, then $A\cap B\neq \varnothing$.

B. Give an example of a measure space $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ and measurable disjoint sets $A,B\in \mathcal{B}$ that satisfy $\mu (A)=\mu (B)=\mu (X)$.

I tried to start with $m([0,1])=1$ and I got stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: B. $B=\cup_[2n+1=2n+2]$

Comment: Proof of A by contradiction: If $A$ and $B$ were disjoint, we could apply additivity of measure to get $m(A\cup B)=m(A)+m(B)>1=m([0,1])$, which is absurd as $A\cup B\subseteq[0,1]$.

Comment: For question B., the measure of $A$, $B$ and $X$ will all have to be infinite. You could take $A = (-\infty, 0)$, $B = [0, \infty)$ and $X = \Bbb{R}$ under the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be two subsets of $[0,1]$.
Then
$$m(A\cup B)=m(A)+m(B)-m(A\cap B)>1-m(A\cap B)$$

Since $A,B\subseteq[0,1]$, this means that $m(A \cup B)\leq 1$. From the first and the second results :
$$m(A\cup B)-m(A\cap B)>1 \text{  and  } m(A \cup B)\leq 1$$
we get that $m(A\cap B)\neq 0$ which means that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$.